# Add UI elements to forgeviewer in angular

Tags: angular, autodesk-forge

I am trying to add the UI elements to the forge viewer in angular. I am able to get the model up and running, and mapped sensors to the model. However, I cant find out how to add the sidebar and header from the reference(hyperion) example, showing sensor data history using graphs. The reference example is written in react, and I have to use angular. Is there a way of integrating this in angular?

All help appreciated!

Comment: can you please add your code on https://stackblitz.com/ for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no angular version of Forge data viz react components, but check this blog. It's showing a possibility to load react components in angular.

https://medium.com/@zacky_14189/embedding-react-components-in-angular-the-easy-way-60f796b68aef